# Where should I start learning Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to learn  a bit of Prolog.

Can anyone recommend a) a good, free implementation on Linux? And b) a good tutorial / cookbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWI-Prolog should be sufficient.  The performance isn't great but its very mature and full-featured.  There is also extensive [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/refman/) for it.  As for an online tutorial, I'd recommend http://www.learnprolognow.org/.  Personally, I learned by taking small projects I'd written in other languages and porting them to Prolog, while trying to avoid assert/retract.

Answer (score 0):

**Prolog Tutorials, Videos, Books and Implementations. Enjy!**

https://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/prolog/

In the above link you find these text tutorials:

- **Introduction to Prolog:** this is a very simple tutorial, but one which deals with some basic issues that other tutorials tend to gloss over.
  http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/.../prolog_tutorial/prologpages/
- **Try Logic Programming! A Gentle Introduction to Prolog:** this is focused on logic programming as a different programming paradigm.
  https://bernardopires.com/.../try-logic-programming-a.../
- **Prolog :- Tutorial:** this is a detailed, example oriented introduction to the language.
  http://www.cpp.edu/~jrf.../www/prolog_tutorial/contents.html
- **Learn Prolog Now:** this is a thorough tutorial that starts at the beginning and gets into advanced subjects.
  http://learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online

[image]