# Learning Prolog Basics

Tags: prolog

I'm pretty close to an exam where I have to answer some questions about Haskell and Prolog.
I would like to find a web like "learnyouahaskell" but about Prolog.

I don't know why logical languages are harder for me, they aren't logical for my knowledge =.=

Any recommends?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589155/where-should-i-start-learning-prolog

Comment: agreed! learnyouahaskell is a great website for learning haskell. I feel like the core principles of how to program in Prolog is much simpler than haskell though, so it probably doesn't need/get as extensive a treatment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the equivalent of leanyouahaskell would be [Learn Prolog Now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/).
also, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401635/good-beginners-material-on-prolog)

It might also help to re-evaluate (or rather backtrack xD) your definition of logical;
for example, when you have

```
x=3
2x=x+1
```

you would normally conclude that there is no x that satisfies this system of equations, not that x is first 3 and then 1 :b

anyway, it's true that it's a bit hard to adjust; good luck with your exam!

Comment: Thank you very much. I've just started with the Prolog. Hope I'll pass the exam!

Answer (score 1):

also this is a very good website for understanding the basics with examples, diagrams and so on:
http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/contents.html

Comment: Dead link. The new link is [Prolog Tutorial](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/contents.html).